# C# or Unity for Cross platform software development. Need advice

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, xamarin, cross-platform

Hi guys I need your advice.

I am planning to start the development of cross platform application. It will be similar to city building game but more precise. With some procedurally generated elements. Lots of buildings, roads and vegetation. For iOS, Mac and PC.

I have experience with Java, C# and Unity. I do have an idea how to do it in Unity. But I have never worked on developing desktop application from the start.

My question are:

1. Is Unity a good option to start with or I am better to start with just with clean C#?
2. Is there a good cross platform 3D graphics library for C#?
3. Is there a good cross platform C# UI library for iOS
4. How good is Xamarin?

I can see advantages using Unity, like I won’t have to program all the graphics. But I would assume C# have some good cross platform graphics api as well.

What do you think?

Comment: First: please post a **single** question. Second. Post **specific** programming-related questions that show what you want to achieve and where you´re stuck. Questions about if or if not something is good are pretty opinion-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be in conflict wether to use Unity or not. You first need to answer a few other questions.

1. How important is performance?
2. How fast do you want the development process to go.
3. How many people are going to work on it.

If you have the time or the resources to go for a clean c# project, go for it. You will be rewarded with excellent performance.
If you have neither, use Unity. You may no longer be able to target really old devices, but you will be able to start it and finish it fairly quickly.

EDIT: The way I worded my answer, it seems like I am dissing on Unity. I am not, as a matter of fact, I kind of love the engine. It does however take a small toll on performance.